# Magento, add a custom attribute to a customer address

Tags: magento

I'm looking for a way to add a drop down for a customer's address (during registration, editing, checkout, etc..) that indicates whether or not it is a Residential or Business address. I have spent hours going through tutorials but they are all out of date or poorly written. I have read 6 different ones telling me how to do the same thing 6 different ways. Can someone outline a simple process that you need to do in order to add a custom attribute to an address? I'm on Magento 1.6

Comment: What approaches have you tried and what problems have you faced?

Comment: I can get the input fields to show up but nothing ever saves to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this tutorial at Fontis: [Know More About Your Customers - Adding Custom Signup Attributes](http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/know-more-about-your-customers-adding-custom-signup-attributes)

Whilst this was written for 1.3.2.4, most (if not all) is still relevant for 1.6. I've done a very similar thing by allowing a customer to choose the customer group they wish to belong to, by following these directions.

Oh, and there are some great comments on the post as well.

Comment: The article referred in this answer is not giving good advice, it suggests to modify core files and to add 'business' code in the templates, thusly breaking magento's MVC architecture.

Comment: @DavidSarmiento Whilst the Magento motto is "Don't f#^@ with the core" what Magento actually mean is "Don't f#^@ with the files in the `/app/code/core` folder as you will lose your changes when upgrading". Taking a copy of a core file and placing into the `/app/code/local` folder is the only way to implement some logic at times and this is what the article is suggesting. Also, what business logic are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

These tutorials should give you a good idea how to do what you want:
http://www.unexpectedit.com/magento/add-new-customer-attribute-onepage-magento-checkout
http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address

Best regards

Comment: The Excellence magento blog article is specially useful.